# Using answers from prompt for a calculation

Tags: javascript

Total newbie at JavaScript.

I would like to calculate how many days one has been alive by asking the user their date of birth via prompts/alerts, then obviously subtracting their date of birth from today's date.

I've made a bit of a start...

```
var month=prompt("Please enter month of birth"," "); 
var day=prompt("Please enter day of birth"," "); 
var year=prompt("Please enter your year of birth"," ");

var curdate = this is the bit i need help with 
var birth = this is the bit i need help with

var milliDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // a day in milliseconds;

var ageInDays = (curdate - birth) / milliDay;

document.write("You have been alive for: " + ageInDays);
```

Any advice or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look into DateJS, it simplifies parsing dates: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: @TJH come on. Let Chad learn base JS before using frameworks and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Date object (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). They can be created from a month, a day, and a year, and added/subtracted.

Typically :

```
var curDate = new Date();
var birth = new Date(year, month, day);

var ageInDays = (curdate.getTime() - birth.getTime()) / milliDay;
```

Be aware of the fact that months starts at 0, e.g. January is 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
var curDate = new Date();
```

gives you the current date.

```
var birthdate = new Date(year, month-1, day);
```

gives you a Date from the separate variables. NB the month is zero-based.

Answer (score 1):

```
end = Date.now(); // Get current time in milliseconds from 1 Jan 1970
var date = 20; //Date you got from the user
var month = 8-1; // Month, subtracted by one because month starts from 0 according to JS
var year = 1996; // Year
//Set date to the old time
obj = new Date();
obj.setDate(date);
obj.setMonth(month);
obj.setYear(year);
obj = obj.getTime(); //Get old time in milliseconds from Jan 1 1970
document.write((end-obj)/(1000*60*60*24));
```

Simply subtract current time from Jan 1 1970 in milliseconds from their birthdate's time from Jan 1 1970 in milliseconds. Then convert it to days. Look at [MDN's Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z9Kj/) for a working example. Try entering yesterday's date. It should show 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

Read some of this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Comment: Please do not promote w3schools. Visit http://w3fools.com for many reasons why. Instead send people to the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/)